# Save attachments to a folder and rename them

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I'm trying to get a VBA macro in Outlook that will save an email's attachment to a specific folder and add the date *received* to the file name.

My googling has gotten me this far:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk (itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Temp\"
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next 
End Sub
```

The first obvious thing is that it's applying the current time to the file name instead of the received time, but I can't seem to change it. My theory is that the Outlook.Attachment doesn't have a `ReceivedTime` and that the email itself has to be referenced.

Secondly, this doesn't seem to work at all, ha! It worked the first day I started tinkering but after that it stopped saving files.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is my Save Attachments script. You select all the messages that you want the attachments saved from, and it will save a copy there. It also adds text to the message body indicating where the attachment is saved. You could easily change the folder name to include the date, but you would need to make sure the folder existed before starting to save files.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete the attachment.
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

        Next i

        ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        ' Check for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If
        objMsg.Save
    End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  The one thing that would be nice is if it handled duplicates - if a file already exists in the destination directory, it will be overwritten.  Is there a "WScript.Shell" command or some other effective way (other than System File Object which is the only thing i am familiar with) to easily determine whether a file already exists in the destination directory and of so make its name unique?

Comment: Warning: Even if `SaveAsFile` fails, the program will continue executing and delete all your attachments.

Comment: @Navin any way to count the number of files in the directory? that way you could see if it matches the number of attachments before you delete them??

Comment: I hope someone has an answer. How to amend the original code for incoming email. The macro works but must be done manually and I want to have it done at the same time emails arrive into my 'Test' folder?

Answer (score 7):

See `ReceivedTime` Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171873(v=office.11).aspx

You added another `\` to the end of `C:\Temp\` in the *SaveAs File* line. Could be a problem. Do a test first before adding a path separator.

```
dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")  
saveFolder = "C:\Temp"
```

You have not set `objAtt` so there is no need for "`Set objAtt = Nothing`". If there was it would be just before `End Sub` not in the loop.

---

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk (itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
    Dim saveFolder As String Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")  saveFolder = "C:\Temp"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Re: It worked the first day I started tinkering but after that it stopped saving files.

> This is usually due to Security settings. It is a "trap" set for first time users to allow macros then take it away.  http://www.slipstick.com/outlook-developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

Answer (score 4):

```vba
Public Sub Extract_Outlook_Email_Attachments()

Dim OutlookOpened As Boolean
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim outAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim outItem As Object
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim outMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim inputDate As String, subjectFilter As String


saveFolder = "Y:\Wingman" ' THIS IS WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE THE ATTACHMENT TO

If Right(saveFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveFolder = saveFolder & "\"

subjectFilter = ("Daily Operations Custom All Req Statuses Report") ' THIS IS WHERE YOU PLACE THE EMAIL SUBJECT FOR THE CODE TO FIND

OutlookOpened = False
On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    OutlookOpened = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If outApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cannot start Outlook.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outFolder = outNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

If Not outFolder Is Nothing Then
    For Each outItem In outFolder.Items
        If outItem.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
            Set outMailItem = outItem
                If InStr(1, outMailItem.Subject, subjectFilter) > 0 Then 'removed the quotes around subjectFilter
                    For Each outAttachment In outMailItem.Attachments
                    outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & outAttachment.filename

                    Set outAttachment = Nothing

                    Next
                End If
        End If
    Next
End If

If OutlookOpened Then outApp.Quit

Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Added simple code to save with readable date-time stamp.

Use **sync2pst** to sync all your data in outlook with all your devices, work like this:

1. you only need to buy 1 license: save your pst file on one computer (let's call this pc 'server') on your network.
2. create scheduled tasks that will synchronize the pst file on your 'server' with all the pst files on all your devices, no matter which device downloaded the emails first (you need some dos programming knowledge to bypass pst files that are open at sync time).
3. save all your attachments on the same skydrive folder that is located on the same place on all your devices (e.g. e:\skydrive\attachments)
4. Use the code below on all your devices to save attachments (change the path as mentioned above)
5. Use **ONLY ONE PST-file** for all your accounts, make folders, subfolders and so ...
6. in VBA: refer to '`microsoft scripting runtime`'extra/references...'
7. here's the code

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
SaveAttachments
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String
Dim fs As FileSystemObject

' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "F:\SkyDrive\Attachments\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.
        Set fs = New FileSystemObject

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = Left(objAttachments.Item(i).FileName, Len(objAttachments.Item(i).FileName) - 4) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Day(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Month(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("0000" + Trim(Str$(Year(Now))), 4) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Hour(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Minute(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Second(Now))), 2) + Right((objAttachments.Item(i).FileName), 4)

            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete the attachment.
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

        Next i

        ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        ' Check for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If

        objMsg.Save
    End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually had solved this not long after posting but failed to post my solution. I honestly don't remember it. But, I had to re-visit the task when I was given a new project that faced the same challenge.

I used the ReceivedTime property of Outlook.MailItem to get the time-stamp, I was able to use this as a unique identifier for each file so they do not override one another.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
        saveFolder = "C:\PathToDirectory\"
    Dim dateFormat As String
        dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks a ton for the other solutions, many of them go above an beyond :)

Comment: This saved me heaps of time trying to create filenames with (1), (2), etc.. Just so much easier to use a datetime

Answer (score 1):

Your question has 2 tasks to be performed. First to extract the Email attachments to a folder and saving or renaming it with a specific name.

If your search can be split to 2 searches you will get more hits. I could refer one page that explains how to save the attachment to a system folder <[Link for the page to save attachments to a folder](http://officetricks.com/save-outlook-mail-attachment-to-local-folder/)>.

Please post any page or code if you have found to save the attachment with specific name.

Comment: In my code above I call the .SaveAsFile method, which takes the full path for the destination file. You could change this code to specify a filename.