# VBA open excel from e-mail in outlook

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

Is it possible to open an excel file from an e-mail via VBA in excel?

example setup:

- daily mail with an excel file attached

Need:

- Opening that attached excel file from excel (via VBA) and saving it to a local location

Is the opening of an excel file stored in outlook even possible in VBA Excel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download attachment from Outlook and Open in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781320/download-attachment-from-outlook-and-open-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Check that link:

[Save attachments to a folder and rename them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/outlook-vba-macro-to-save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them)

To open an Excel file in VBA:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\\attachment.xls"
```