# Save Outlook attachment to disk

Tags: vba, outlook

I found *numerous* examples of VBA scripts to automatically move attachments to my hard drive. This one I've found online works when I run the macro in Outlook as is, but will not work when I set it to a rule.

When I run the macro without the "item as outlook.mailitem" parameter in the sub header and have the email containing the file I want saved selected, it will function properly.

However, as soon as I add that information so I can run it as a rule, outlook throws an error and it disables the rule.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub moveAttachmentsAlpha(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = "C:\DailyFlash\"
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
lngCount = objAttachments.Count
strDeletedFiles = ""

If lngCount > 0 Then

' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
' confused and only every other item is removed.

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

        ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
        ' Get the file name.
        strFile = objAttachments.item(i).FileName

    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

    'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
    'check for html and use html tags in link
    If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
        Else
        strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
        strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
    End If

    'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
    'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

Next i

' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
' Check for HTML body
If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
    objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
Else
    objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" &  objMsg.HTMLBody
End If
    objMsg.Save
End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks like it came from this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/outlook-vba-macro-to-save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them). The script provided was designed to work with `.Selection`. You can convert it for use in a rule but you need to use `Item` when referencing mail in the rest of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep most of the script. Remove the reference to `Outlook.Selection` and the for loop associated to it. Then, in it's place, assign `item` to `objMsg` to allow the rest of the of the script to function as normal. After testing I have decided to steal it and use it myself as well.

```
Public Sub moveAttachmentsAlpha(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = "C:\temp\"
On Error Resume Next

Set objMsg = item

' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
lngCount = objAttachments.Count
strDeletedFiles = ""

If lngCount > 0 Then

    ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
    ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
    ' confused and only every other item is removed.

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

        ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
        ' Get the file name.
        strFile = objAttachments.item(i).FileName

        ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
        strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

        ' Save the attachment as a file.
        objAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

        'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
        'check for html and use html tags in link
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
        Else
            strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
            strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
        End If

    Next i

    ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
    ' Check for HTML body
    If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
    Else
        objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
    End If
    objMsg.Save
End If

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

FYI: I changed nothing after the line `' This code only strips attachments from mail items.` Except for a `Next`