# Save Outlook attachment to disk with size filter

Tags: vba, outlook, size, attachment

referring to the amazing script found here [Save Outlook attachment to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225014/save-outlook-attachment-to-disk)

I'd like to filter attachments on size. I am using the script for a while now, but the script also saves company logo's etc. This gives numerous 1kb files and changes the mail layout.

I would like the script to ignore files smaller than 10kb. Is there anyone who can help me implement this in the script below;

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim pobjMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection

' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next
 
' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 
' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
For Each pobjMsg In objSelection
SaveAttachments_Parameter pobjMsg
Next
 
ExitSub:
 
Set pobjMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
 
Public Sub SaveAttachments_Parameter(objMsg As MailItem)
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String
 
' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next
 
' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "\\path\"
 
' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
lngCount = objAttachments.Count
 
If lngCount > 0 Then
 
' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
' confused and only every other item is removed.
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
 
' Save attachment before deleting from item.
' Get the file name.
strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
'=======================================================

tempstr = strFile 'strtoclean
charArray = Array("?", "/", "\", ":", "*", """", "<", ">", ",", "&", "#", "~", "%", "{", "}", "+", "_")

For Each tmpChar In charArray

Select Case tmpChar
Case "&"
changeTo = " and "
Case ":"
changeTo = "-"
Case Else
changeTo = " "
End Select

tempstr = Replace(tempstr, tmpChar, changeTo)
Next

strFile = tempstr



'==========================================================


' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
strFile = strFolderpath & Format(objMsg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-MM-dd h-mm-ss") & "." & strFile
 
' Save the attachment as a file.
objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
 
' Delete the attachment.
objAttachments.Item(i).Delete
 
'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
'check for html and use html tags in link
If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
Else
strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
End If
     
Next i
End If
 
' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
' Check for HTML body
If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
objMsg.Body = objMsg.Body & vbCrLf & _
"The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles
Else
objMsg.HTMLBody = objMsg.HTMLBody & "" & _
"The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & ""
End If
objMsg.Save
ExitSub:
 
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub



Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. You missed the comment "Warning: Even if SaveAsFile fails, the program will continue executing and delete all your attachments.".  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15531505/1571407.  This may be useful  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#On_Error_Resume_Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Attachment.Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.size) property which might help.

You can do

```
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
   if objAttachments.Item(i).Size >= 10240 then
       ...
   end if
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you ellaborate the 3 dots?

Comment: You already looping thru the attachments with `For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1 ... Next i`. To ignore attachments smaller than 10kb, check the size of each attachment right inside the loop. So the 3 dots is your current code in that loop. Let me know if you need to more help on this.

Comment: thanks, I got it working