# Update the file name on Workbook_BeforeSave

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have Excel save a file with a unique name whenever it's saved.
  This will mostly be used within Excel 2003, but must also work on 2010.

The idea is that the user opens a template file and if they click 'Save' or just close the workbook it will save as template_1, template_2, etc.

**This works fine if they click 'Save', but if they close the file it will ask if you want to save changes on the original file, saves it under the new name and then ask if the user wants to save changes... and then saves and asks if the user wants to save changes, and so on.**  Obviously, I only want it to save the once and then close - but it doesn't.

I've tried setting the `Saved` property to TRUE. I've tried `Cancel = True` after the save but this causes Excel to crash with a **Excel has encountered a problem and really needs to screw your day up** type message.

In the code below I've tried removing the `Saved=TRUE` and the `Cancel=TRUE`, I've tried moving them around - Cancel before the Save, Cancel after the Save but within the `If...End If` block, before and after the `EnableEvents` code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NewFileName As String

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    NewFileName = GenerateUniqueName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    If NewFileName <> "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs NewFileName, ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

FastExit:

    Cancel = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
        " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeSave." & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "DOCUMENT NOT SAVED.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Resume FastExit

End Sub
```

The `GenerateUniqueName` code is below - this assumes the file name doesn't contain an underscore character and appends the number to the file name as _1, _2, etc:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' GenerateUniqueName
'
'   Generates a file name that doesn't exist by appending a number
'   inbetween the base name and the extension.
'   Example: GenerateUniqueName("c:\folder\file.ext") = "c:\folder\file_4.ext"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GenerateUniqueName(FullFileName As String, Optional fAlwaysAddNumber As Boolean) As String

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not oFSO.FileExists(FullFileName) And Not fAlwaysAddNumber Then
        GenerateUniqueName = FullFileName
    Else
        Dim strExt As String
        Dim strNonExt As String
        Dim strBaseName As String
        Dim strNewName As String
        Dim i As Integer
        strExt = oFSO.GetExtensionName(FullFileName)
        If strExt <> "" Then
            strBaseName = oFSO.GetBaseName(FullFileName)
            If InStrRev(strBaseName, "_") > 0 Then
                i = Val(Mid(strBaseName, InStrRev(strBaseName, "_") + 1, Len(strBaseName)))
                strBaseName = Left(strBaseName, InStrRev(strBaseName, "_") - 1)
            End If
            strNonExt = oFSO.buildpath(oFSO.GetParentFolderName(FullFileName), strBaseName)
            Do
                i = i + 1
                strNewName = strNonExt & "_" & i & "." & strExt
            Loop While oFSO.FileExists(strNewName)
            GenerateUniqueName = strNewName
        Else
            MsgBox "File name must contain a file extension." & vbCr & _
                "e.g. .xls or .xlsx", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            GenerateUniqueName = ""
        End If
    End If

    Set oFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: How about adding "activeworkbook.save false" after your code saves the book?

Comment: If your user first does a `Save` and immediately after does a `Close`, do you want **2** distinct copies of the file saved ??

Comment: @Absinthe - `.Save False` isn't a VBA command (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585.aspx). @Gary's Student - I'd expect it not to save when closed in that instance as the previous save would mark Excels "dirty flag" as clean.

Comment: Sorry, I meant .Close false

Comment: Even though @Mr.Burns comment about `ActiveWorkbook.Close False` has been deleted it did give me an idea which appears to have worked. @Absinthe - guess your comment was the same as Mr.Burns.  I can't put `.Close` in the BeforeSave as it would close the file if they only saved the file, but I can check the BeforeClose event.  I'll put it as an answer and see if anyone can see a problem with it.

Comment: `but if they close the file it will auto-save with the updated file name` How does the autosave happen?

Comment: You're dead right there @Siddharth - it doesn't auto-save, it asks if you want to save the file, saves it and then asks if  you want to save the file, etc.  I'll update the question so it doesn't look like I'm making it up as I go along. :)

Comment: Yup, I meant in before close. Need coffee.

Comment: I thought so :) Anyways check the answer that I posted. let me know if I missed anything and I will rectify it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this and see if your problems are solved? I have not included your function below as that remains unchanged.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Ret As Variant

    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

        Ret = MsgBox("Would you like to save this workbook?", vbYesNo)

        If Ret = vbYes Then SaveWithUniqueName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = True Then Exit Sub

    If SaveAsUI = True Then Exit Sub '~~> Checks for Save As

    Cancel = True
    SaveWithUniqueName
End Sub

Sub SaveWithUniqueName()
    Dim NewFileName As String

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

        NewFileName = GenerateUniqueName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

    If NewFileName <> "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs NewFileName, ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

FastExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
        " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeSave." & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "DOCUMENT NOT SAVED.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Resume FastExit
End Sub
```

Comment: That works, thanks Siddharth.  I'll take it over my answer as it still allows for `Save As`, asks about Saving on BeforeClose and looks tidier.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my `BeforeSave` code slightly - I'm still not sure if     `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True : Cancel = True` is correct, but I do know it crashes if I don't put in the `Cancel = True`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NewFileName As String

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Cancel = True

    NewFileName = GenerateUniqueName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    If NewFileName <> "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs NewFileName, ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

FastExit:

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
        " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ThisWorkbook.Workbook_BeforeSave." & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "DOCUMENT NOT SAVED.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Resume FastExit

End Sub
```

This will Save the file with a new name, but not close it.

As Absinthe and Mr.Burns said - look at the close event.
This looks to see if the workbook has been saved.  If it hasn't then the close event is cancelled, the workbook is saved and then it's closed otherwise it will just close without saving.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim NewFileName As String

    If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then
        Cancel = True
        NewFileName = GenerateUniqueName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        If NewFileName <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs NewFileName, ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            ThisWorkbook.Close Not ThisWorkbook.Saved
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone spot any pitfalls here?
**Edit:** I've found one pitfall - you can't use `Save As`.

Comment: is this an actual answer or an edit to your original question? if it's an edit, please edit your original question and remove this answer.

Comment: I've put it as an answer as it does resolve the problem by adding code to the `BeforeClose` event which I hadn't done previously, and was pointed out in the comment made by Absinthe.  I think if I add it to my original question it will become more of a statement and less of a question.