# Email attachment export into specific folder file format issue

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I am currently receiving weekly reports on outlook which I need to open and save in a specific folder. I have succeeded in renaming the file and transferring it to the desired file.

HOWEVER, the file format isn't the same as the file which is attached to the email, it is either registered as type "file" when I do not put a date format at the end or a type ".2016" file when I put one. When opened in Notepad the information is unreadable

Here is the code I currently use:

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormatdateFormat = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
saveFolder = "C:\Users\mypathtotheattachment"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & "thenewnameofmyattachment" & ".csv"
Next
End Sub
```

Any help is welcome, I scanned all over the place for any information but I'm stuck...

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you leave the name the same? E.g. if you do objAtt.SaveAsFile objAtt FileName?

Comment: @Charlie thanks for your answer unfortunately I tried changing to objAtt.FileName and now my macro isn't running anymore for a reason I can't explain...

Comment: Well I would start with that - the way to save all attachments is well documented and should work e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them

Comment: I worked starting from this thread but (when it worked) it just didn't export the right format and now it doesn't work at all, I check the macros authorisations, the digital signature etc. but it doesn't seem linked to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your trying to do?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveAtmtToDisk(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim FileName As String

'   //  Saved Location
    SavePath = "C:\temp\"

'   // 05 24 2016 Antoine.csv
    FileName = Format(Now, "DD MM YYYY") & " Antoine.csv"

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
         Atmt.SaveAsFile SavePath & "\" & FileName
    Next

    Set Atmt = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Tested on Outlook 2010*

Comment: Thanks @Om3r , it's almost that, but I'd like to put the date after and I think this is what messes up the format because I also tried:

`Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
 Dim saveFolder As String
 Dim dateFormat
 dateFormat = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
 saveFolder = "C:\Users\etc"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & "newname" & dateFormat
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next objAtt
    End Sub`

But the format saves a .2016 file so i tried: & ".csv"
Is it possible to combine the 2?

Comment: It's all good I switched it around and found what I wanted by doing 
`FileName = "Antoine" & Format(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY") & ".csv" `
Thanks @Om3r and @Charlie