# How to import emails into ms access and save their attachment to a network drive which can be referenced by access

Tags: ms-access, outlook

I am attempting to set up a way to take invoices that are emailed to me and import them into MS Access so that I can track completion of payment and vouchering and at a later time set up a better system for accounts payable.

I have been researching how to go about linking outlook and access for this purpose but I don't actually get the attachment when I link a folder with my database.  I have found people suggesting that I don't actually save the file to access because it will bloat the database and instead just save the file location.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find information about how to actually go about this process.  Right now I have rules set up in Outlook to sort the invoices I receive by vendor, which I could then link to access.  But there is no information regarding the attachment except that it has one.

Any pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, I get the feeling that a lot of this will need to be done in outlook somehow, but I don't really know where to begin with it.

I can figure out how to save the attachments to a folder, but the thing I can't figure out is how to link outlook and access so that access can have a hyperlink to where the attachment is saved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save attachments to a folder and rename them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them)

Comment: That does seem to give me a great way to save the attachments but the tricky part is linking the inbox folders with ms access and having access know where the file is stored so I can have a hyperlink to the document.  But thanks for showing me this.